# Gridview sorting - MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback = true does not work

Tags: asp.net, gridview, maintainscrollpositionon

I have a gridview on a web page. I wanted to maintain the scroll position everytime it postbacks after sorting gridview.
I have included MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback attribute in the page directive, also included below in Page_load

```
Page.MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback = true
```

But it does not work.After post back it always goes to the top of the page. Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to use your gridview inside update panel as mentioned here-

[Maintain horizontal and vertical ScrollPosition on Postback in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3448694/maintain-horizontal-and-vertical-scrollposition-on-postback-in-asp-net)